# How to set ImageView URI with URI String?

Tags: android, uri

I have an app where a user can find an image from the gallery and it will be shown on the screen through a button click. The user can exit the app and the image they chose can be saved, so when they click the button again, it will also be shown. The image is shown the first time when it is picked, but the saving functionality does not seem to be working since the image is not being shown after the user closes and reopens the app.

I have tried looking up what camera permissions I may need, but I have not had any luck. I don't know what I would need since the app is able to load the image the first time.

---

//This is the method that shows the image

```
public void showImage(View view)
{

    LinearLayout scroll = findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
    for(String i: imgDataList){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(i));
        scroll.addView(image);
    }
}
```

---

//This is the method that works with the image that is gotten from the gallery

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String imgData = data.getDataString();
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                imgDataList.add(imgData);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                imgDataList.add(imgData);
            }
            break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `sharedPreferences` to store you image `uri` 
please read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) about `sharedPreferences` and Save key-value `data`